# Issue with absolute positioned divs in no-overflow 100vh body on iPad's Safari

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a SPA with `overflow: hidden` on body and I have two toolbars (one at `top: 0` and the other at `bottom: 0`).

Something like that:

```css
* { margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; }

#main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
}

#top { top: 0; }
#bottom { bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="top" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="bottom" class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

It does the job. It's easy. **BUT**, because there are some form elements on the toolbars recently I discovered my layout is affected by this [*input element on fixed modal*](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8) bug. So, as a workaround (as suggested in the linked article), I just changed `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` for class `bar`. Apparently it works. But now iPad renders the layout as if it doesn't fit in 100vh and there's a little annoying scroll, even though the `overflow: hidden`.

**Screenshots**

- On iPad with `position: fixed`

[image: On iPad with position fixed]

- On iPad with `position: absolute`

[image]

Any ideas on how to avoid/fix this issue? (besides using `position: fixed` of course)

Comment: try putting all your content inside a div with `position: absolute; height:100%; width:100%; top:0; left:0`

Comment: I have found position fixed elements usually  work best if they are direct children of the body, otherwise you get things like this happening